# Web Api return null value on response body Postman

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, postman

I'm inserting data into a SQL Server database using .NET Web API and a stored procedure. `Customer_id` were generated by SQL statement and `temp_token` are using JSON object and encryption to be generated. Others were from user requests.

When I check on SQL Server database, the data was inserted, but when on Postman the `customer_id` and `temp_token` are returned as a null value.

JSON Response

```
{
    "Customer_id": null,
    "full_name": "Hahahaha",
    "phone_number": "0158493215",
    "gender": "M",
    "id_number": "951123035908",
    "dob": "1/11/1995",
    "nationality": "MY",
    "user_id": "jahat1@ikonp.com",
    "secure_word": "netvista277707",
    "provider_id": "lifecare.com",
    "email":"jahat1@ikonp.com",
    "temp_token": null,
}
```

Stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SSO_REGISTER]
    @customer_id nvarchar(255) OUTPUT,
    @secure_word nvarchar(255),
    @full_name nvarchar(255),
    @phone_number nvarchar(255),
    @nationality nvarchar(255),
    @id_number nvarchar(255),
    @dob nvarchar(255),
    @email nvarchar(255),
    @user_id nvarchar(255),
    @provider_id nvarchar(255),
    @temp_token nvarchar(255),
    @tac nvarchar(6),
    @gender nvarchar(255)
AS
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SSO WHERE EMAIL= @EMAIL) < 1
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT OFF;

        UPDATE ST_YIBANCANSHU 
        SET @customer_id = (SELECT CONCAT(parmvalstr1, FORMAT(parmvalint,parmvalstr2), '_', YEAR(GETDATE()))  
                            FROM ST_YIBANCANSHU 
                            WHERE parmtyp = 'RUNNING_NUM' AND parmkey = 'GUKE'), 
            parmvalint = parmvalint + 1
        WHERE 
            parmtyp = 'RUNNING_NUM' AND parmkey = 'GUKE'
    
        INSERT INTO SSO (CUSTOMER_ID, SECURE_WORD, FULL_NAME, PHONE_NUMBER, NATIONALITY, ID_NUMBER, DOB, EMAIL, GENDER)
        VALUES (@customer_id, @secure_word, @full_name, @phone_number, @nationality, @id_number, @dob, @email, @gender)

        INSERT INTO ACCOUNT_INFO (CUSTOMER_ID, USER_ID, PROVIDER_ID, TEMP_TOKEN, TAC)
        VALUES (@customer_id, @user_id, @provider_id, @temp_token, @tac)
    END
```

Controller class

```
[Route("api/Account/Register")]
public HttpResponseMessage DoRegister([FromBody] SSO_Model value)
{
    if (value is null) 
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, value);

    // SSO_Model _return = value;
    try
    {
        SSOService sso_service = new SSOService();
        sso_service.Register(value);

        if (value is null)
            throw new Exception("Failed to register.");
        else
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.full_name)) 
                throw new Exception("Failed to create appointment.");

        JObject _jo = new JObject
                      {
                          { value },
                          { "Response:", Constant.RESP_SUCCESSFUL}
                      };
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _jo);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        JObject _jo = new JObject
                          {
                              { "Response: {", Constant.RESP_INVALID_REQUEST +
                                          Constant.RESP_INVALID_REQUEST_MESSAGE + "}"
                          }
    };

    // HttpError err = new HttpError(Constant.RESP_INVALID_REQUEST_MESSAGE ? ex.Message.Substring(0, Constant.EX_MSG_LEN) + "..." : ex.Message);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, _jo);
}
```

Services class

```
public SSO_Model Register(SSO_Model objsso)
{
        SSO_Model _return = null;

        try
        {
            string tac = " ";
            string temp_token = " ";
            Test util = new Test();
            tac = Test.getTac();

            JObject _jo = new JObject
                {
                    { "Secure Word", objsso.secure_word },
                    { "EXP", DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30) },

                };

            temp_token = Encryption.Encrypt(_jo.ToString(), Constant.ENC_KEY);
            
            string customer_id = " ";

            SqlParameter _sp = new SqlParameter();
            _sp.ParameterName = "@customer_id";
            _sp.DbType = DbType.String;
            _sp.Size = 255;
            _sp.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            SqlParameter[] parm =
            {
                _sp,
                //new SqlParameter("customer_id", customer_id ),
                new SqlParameter("full_name", objsso.full_name),
                new SqlParameter("phone_number", objsso.phone_number),
                new SqlParameter("gender", objsso.gender),
                new SqlParameter("id_number", objsso.id_number),
                new SqlParameter("secure_word", objsso.secure_word),
                new SqlParameter("nationality", objsso.nationality),
                new SqlParameter("dob", objsso.dob),

                new SqlParameter("email", objsso.email),
                new SqlParameter("user_id", objsso.email),

                new SqlParameter("provider_id", objsso.provider_id),
                new SqlParameter("temp_token", temp_token),
                new SqlParameter("tac", tac)
            };

            var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
            ConnectionStrings["_cs"].ConnectionString;

            dbUtil db = new dbUtil(connectionString);
            SqlParameterCollection _xxx = db.ExecNonQueryWithOutput("SSO_REGISTER", parm);
            //db.ExecNonQuery("SSO_REGISTER", parm);

            //_return = true;

            _return = new SSO_Model()
            {
                customer_id = Convert.ToString(_xxx["@customer_id"].Value),
                temp_token = Convert.ToString(_xxx["@temp_token"].Value)
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return _return;
}
```

Model class

```
public class SSO_Model
{
    public string customer_id { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
    public string secure_word { get; set; }
    public string phone_number { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string id_number { get; set; }
    public string dob { get; set; }
    public string nationality { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string temp_token { get; set; }
    public string provider_id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried getting the value using `customer_id = _sp.Value`? Once the query gets executed you can fetch the output parameter value this way. You can also get the token from `temp_token` directly. Also you need to set the value of `objsso`. If you need to use the `new` keyword then you need to have it as a `ref` parameter.

Comment: You are not assigning these values to your object. You are calling sso_service.Register(value); but you are not assigning the result to any variable and you don't change the value of the object named value in service method

Comment: Can you elobarate more @adolja on "you are not assigning the result to any variable and you don't change the value of the object named value in service method"

Comment: In neither the C# code nor the stored procedure code do you declare `@temp_token` as an output parameter, nor do you seem to apply any value to it from SQL. Also `Encryption.Encrypt` returns a `byte[]` result, so storing it into `nvarchar(255)` probably isn't going to work.